# Sum of Dirac functions

Tags: dirac-delta, neural-networks

The Dirac function is commonly used to model the action potential of neurons, and in the text I am reading the "neural response function" is defined as:

$$\rho(t) = \sum_{i=1}^n \delta(t - t_i)$$

The author then follows to say that any well-behaved function h(t) can be expressed as such:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n h(t - t_i) = \int_0^T h(\tau)\rho(t-\tau)d\tau$$

I am confused on two points

1. Wouldn't the first function simply be 1 for all $t$, since the integral of the delta function is 1 by definition?  If so, I do not understand the purpose of the function $\rho(t)$.
2. Related to my confusion on the first point I am simply not following this identity.  I understand the left half of the equation to essentially be an integral of the shifted function $h(t)$, but then the right hand side is the integral of $h(\tau)$ multiplied by $\rho(t-\tau)$, the latter of which is one for every $\tau$.  So as I follow it the right hand side is simply the integral of $h(\tau)$ and the $\rho(t-\tau)$ contributes nothing.

Does anyone understand this enough to explain why this identity is true or useful?

Thank you!

Comment: What's the paper you are reading?

Comment: The identity is true, but it's useful only for people knowing the difference between sum and integral. To those who don't, it can't be explained.

Comment: The text is "Theoretical Neuroscience: Computational and Mathematical Modeling of Neural Systems".

Comment: Here is the link to the text: 
http://cns-classes.bu.edu/cn510/Papers/Theoretical%20Neuroscience%20Computational%20and%20Mathematical%20Modeling%20of%20Neural%20Systems%20-%20%20Peter%20Dayan,%20L.%20F.%20Abbott.pdf

Comment: And the text in question is on page 7

Comment: In general $h \ast \delta(t-a) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty h(t-\tau) \delta(\tau-a) d\tau = h(t-a)$. Thus $h \ast \sum_{i=1}^n \delta(t-t_i) = \sum_{i=1}^n h(t-t_i)$. Here the author replaced $\int_{-\infty}^\infty$ by $\int_0^T$ to show both $h$ and $\rho$ are causal

Comment: I understand this topic may be basic for this community, and I appreciate all your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could convince yourself the identity works as follows:

$$\int_0^T h(\tau) \rho (t - \tau) \mathrm{d} \tau = \int_0^T h(\tau) \sum_{i=1}^n \delta (t - t_i - \tau) \mathrm{d} \tau = \\ \int_0^T h(\tau) \delta (t -t_1 - \tau) \mathrm{d} \tau  + \int_0^T h(\tau) \delta (t -t_2- \tau) \mathrm{d} \tau  +\cdots +\int_0^T h(\tau) \delta (t -t_n- \tau) \mathrm{d} \tau  = \\
h(t -t_1) + h(t-t_2) + \cdots h(t-t_n) = \sum_{i_1}^n h(t-t_i)$$

hopefully this hints at how the "Dirac comb", the sum of Dirac deltas, is sampling out values in the integral and yielding the sum with the function $h$

Comment: Thank you!  Even simply searching on "Dirac comb" helped clear my confusion on this.

Answer (score 0):

observe that :

$\delta(t)$ concentrates at $t=0$, so $\delta(t-t_i)$ (as a function of $t$) concentrates at $t=t_i$, so $\rho(t)$ concentrates at $t=t_1,t_2,\dots,t_n$, so $\rho(t-\tau)$ (as a function of $\tau$) concentrates at $\tau=t-t_1,t-t_2,\dots,t-t_n$.

assume $t_1,t_2,\dots,t_n\in [0,T]$, hence $\int_0^Th(\tau)\rho(t-\tau)d\tau=\sum_{i=1}^n h(t-t_i)$.